# Excluding Products from Search

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, search, catalogsearch

I run a webstore selling automotive products. In the automotive industry, it is very common for a single letter in a vehicle's badge to indicate a significant difference (e.g., AWD indicated by an "X" in the badge). For these types of situations, we'd like to be able to disclude the latter products from the search results.

For example, if a user searches "G35", only products containing "G35" should be returned **and NOT** products containing "G35X".

Is this possible with built-in Magento tools, or will I have to find a 3rd party solution or develop my own? If anyone has experience a plugin that may offer such functionality I'd very much welcome the input!